# SQL: find row from range of dates

Tags: mysql, between

Have table with dates

```
id    name    date_from    date_to
1     one     2015-01-01   2016-12-31
2     two     2017-01-01   2017-02-01
3     three   2017-05-01   2017-06-14

SELECT id FROM table WHERE my_date BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

How to write sql for selecting id where my_date is from range (column date_from and column date_to). For example if `my_date = '2017-01-15'` then result will be `2`

Comment: AFAIK your current query should be already doing that.  What output are you getting?

Comment: I would ask you what types are the `date_from` and `date_to` columns, but even if they were text your query should still be working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen date_from and date_to are `DATE` type

Comment: Hang on, let me create a Fiddle for you...

Comment: @Ing. Michal Hudak: Anyway, please answer Tim's first question: what does your query do you are not satisfied with?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and your query should generally work.

Here is just proof:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e13ec/1

```
SELECT id 
FROM `table` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('2017-01-15','%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN date_from AND date_to;
```